# Getting date difference and output: Years - Months

Tags: python, jinja2

How can I get the difference of two dates and output something like `1 Year 3 months`?

I am using [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/) Template engine. currently I have:

```
{{ context.job_history|map(attribute="to_")|first - context.job_history|map(attribute="from_")|first  }}
```

Which outputs:

> 370 days

I have tried:

```
{{ (context.job_history|map(attribute="to_")|first - context.job_history|map(attribute="from_")|first)/365  }}
```

But this gives me a `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'datetime.timedelta' and 'int'
```

I think(personal opinion) that the Jinja2 syntax is close to python syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.days` attribute of the returned `datetime.timedelta` object:

```
{{ (context.job_history|map(attribute="to_")|first - context.job_history|map(attribute="from_")|first).days/365  }}
```

but you really want to build such information in your Python view code.

Comment: This solves the `TypeError`, thanks, but How would I get output like `1 year 3 months`?

Comment: @Renier You really should write your own formatter for that. Specifying it within the template will be not only very difficult, but also highly confusing.

Comment: @Renier: Really, do this in Python code; then you can use `divmod(td, 365)` to get years and remaining days, then another `divmod(remainder, 30)` to get months, for example. Don't do this in templating code.